# Lock screen w/ slock after a certain time?

Tags: security, xorg, openbox, screen-lock

I am running OpenBox in Arch Linux, how can I set it up so that I can have [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) lock my screen after a certain amount of time (with no activity)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>(I assume you mean after a certain amount of time with no activity)</sub>

`slock` doesn't have that capability built-in; you have to use another tool that watches X and tracks how long there's been no activity. For example, using [xautolock](http://freshmeat.net/projects/xautolock/) with a delay of 15 minutes:

```
$ xautolock -time 15 -locker slock
```